# How to debug Google Chrome (not Chromium) on OS X with source?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, debugging, debug-symbols

The "Warn Before Quitting" feature stopped working for me. When I click Cmd-Q Chrome closes immediately instead of showing me the "Hold ⌘Q to close" message.

I want to debug the code responsible for that, but I can't seem to find a way. On Windows I can attach to Chrome, get the PDBs from Google's symbol server, and get the appropriate sources using SrcSrv.

Is there anything similar on OS X?

(Firefox apparently has a [script to download symbols for Linux/OS X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_symbol_server#Downloading_symbols_on_Linux_Mac_OS_X), though I never tried using it.)

It doesn't happen on another user on my machine or on Chromium. I tried copying my profile to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` of another user and to `~/Library/Application Support/Chromium` (for a Chromium build I made). In both cases the bug did not present itself (though other bad things have happened), so using Chromium doesn't seem like a solution.

(Although I did build Chromium's HEAD rather than the tag corresponding to the version of Google Chrome I'm running. Maybe if I do that I would be able to reproduce the problem in Chromium. Nonetheless the question remains.)

Is it possible to perform source debugging of Google Chrome on OS X? If so, how?

---

Note: I'm not interested in attempts to solve the "Warn Before Quitting" bug, suggestions to report it to Google, etc. That's not the point. I want to be able to debug Chrome myself.